# reactive forms with data from Input and changing the value format

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

I have reactive forms that takes values form @Input.
All values are seen in Html but I want to change the value's format in `<input matInput`
In my example I have date that I want to have in specific format. With @Input data I am doing it in a way:

```
{{Inputdata.date| date: "dd.MM.y"}}
```

But in case I have elements in my Reactive Form:

```html
<tr>
            <td>
                Date
            </td>
            <td>
                <mat-form-field color="warn">
                    <input matInput type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="date">
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
</tr>
```

This is an example of date format but I would also like to have possibility to use select option too.

Is it possible?

Comment: earlier I was doing it with NgModel but it will be deprecated. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used datePicker. It solved my problem.